# AlertDialog with spinner on start of activity

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog, oncreate

I am trying to create an AlertDialog with a spinner on the start of an activity.  I have the following code within the activity's onCreate() method.

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 AlertDialog alertDialog;
 Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
                                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
         this, R.array.num_players_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

 builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
 alertDialog = builder.create();
 alertDialog.show();
```

This force closes every time.  I have successfully created a simple AlertDialog on the start of an activity by using the following code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Stackoverflow!").create().show();
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `AlertDialog.Builder`s `setView()` method to set your created `View` `layout` as the dialog's view.

```
builder.setView(layout);
```

---

In any case, it might be helpful to post the output of `adb logcat` to find out what exception is crashing your app.

Comment: Also, your line `builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);` is redundant as you already did that in the first line.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem but created a new one ha.  Now it displays the dialog with spinner on the start of activity, but when I click on the spinner it crashes.  Sorry for my ignorance, but how do I get the output from the adb logcat? thanks again.

Comment: Open a shell and type `adb logcat` to fetch the logs from your device. Also, if you are developing with Eclipse, the "Debug"-perspective contains a "Log Cat"-pane.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I found the exception, googled it and found an answer.  It now works properly!