# how to put an array into a spinner in an alert box?

Tags: android, arrays, spinner, android-alertdialog

I have an array and I was wondering how I could get it into a spinner that is also in a alert dialog? I know this is a 2 part question but if anyone can help me with one of them it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your array is called spinnerArray, you can use a ArrayAdapter to talk to the spinner::

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
             (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

For [dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), there is already a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132512/alertdialog-with-spinner-on-start-of-activity) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020077/implementing-a-spinner-inside-a-custom-alertdialog) related to using spinners in them.